# How to use paginaton in flutter video player?

Tags: flutter, flutter-video-player

I am using flutter video_player library and I want to play a long list of videos but fetching only 3 videos at a time from the server?

Comment: Maybe the server has a limitation like server-side paging. Please provide your question with your related code.

Comment: @Akif, thank you for commenting, my code is nothing more than sample code given in flutter video_player library.